# linux gpg keys security, red hat and debian

Tags: ubuntu, fedora, gnupg

There is some difference in terms of security between gpg keys generated with a Red Hat based linux distribution like Fedora and gpg keys generated with a Debian based distribution like Ubutnu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference in the security of keys generated across distributions.  Both types of systems use the same PRNG seeded from the same operating system sources (`/dev/random` or `/dev/urandom`).  This is even true of the same versions of GnuPG on other, non-Linux systems like FreeBSD or OpenBSD, which, while they have their own operating system PRNG, provide strong CSPRNG implementations suitable for generating secure keys.

You may use whichever OS you like to generate your keys and use them for signing and encryption.  Other things that are much more important to security include choosing a strong passphrase, picking an appropriate key type (algorithm and size), and keeping your system secure.